# Invalid packed transaction

Tags: nodeos, cleos, eosjs, eosio-code

I am trying RPC API. Here is the code which I am using on cmd for testing a dummy transaction.

```
curl --request POST --url http://localhost:8080/v1/chain/push_transaction --header 'accept: application/json' --header 'content-type: application/json' --data '{"signatures":["EOS4wJVpa8YBT1BnBtGHXM8PgQr9cxD2TuZVGhciLZZwp4AsjStoC"],"compression":false,"packed_context_free_data":"00","packed_trx":"00"}'
```

But each time I get same error message:

> {"code":500,"message":"Internal Service Error","error":{"code":3010010,"name":"packed_transaction_type_exception","what":"Invalid packed transaction","details":[{"message":"Invalid packed transaction","file":"chain_plugin.cpp","line_number":1562,"method":"push_transaction"},{"message":"pivot != std::string::npos: No delimiter in string, cannot determine type: EOS4wJVpa8YBT1BnBtGHXM8PgQr9cxD2TuZVGhciLZZwp4AsjStoC","file":"signature.cpp","line_number":20,"method":"parse_base58"},{"message":"error parsing signature","file":"signature.cpp","line_number":28,"method":"parse_base58"},{"message":"Failed to deserialize variant","file":"abi_serializer.hpp","line_number":697,"method":"from_variant"}]}}

Not sure what is wrong there. I want to use it in one PHP application so RPC is important for me.

**UPDATE**

Then tried solution with SIG_K1_ and SIG_R1_ also.

```
curl --request POST --url http://localhost:8080/v1/chain/push_transaction --header 'accept: application/json' --header 'content-type: application/json' --data '{"signatures":["SIG_K1_EOS4wJVpa8YBT1BnBtGHXM8PgQr9cxD2TuZVGhciLZZwp4AsjStoC"],"compression":false,"packed_context_free_data":"00","packed_trx":"00"}'
```

But it throw some different error like below.

> {"code":500,"message":"Internal Service Error","error":{"code":3010010,"name":"packed_transaction_type_exception","what":"Invalid packed transaction","details":[{"message":"Invalid packed transaction","file":"chain_plugin.cpp","line_number":1562,"method":"push_transaction"},{"message":"Unable to decode base58 string EOS4wJVpa8YBT1BnBtGHXM8PgQr9cxD2TuZVGhciLZZwp4AsjStoC","file":"base58.cpp","line_number":625,"method":"from_base58"},{"message":"error parsing signature","file":"signature.cpp","line_number":28,"method":"parse_base58"},{"message":"Failed to deserialize variant","file":"abi_serializer.hpp","line_number":697,"method":"from_variant"}]}}

FYI, I am using cleos wallet keys to see the signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the public Key as your signature instead of signature itself and you have to provide a signature-base-prefix/signature-prefix because you can use different curve-algorithms to create keys (R1/K1).

```
... "signatures":["EOS4wJVpa8YBT1BnBtGHXM8PgQr9cxD2TuZVGhciLZZwp4AsjStoC"]...
```

must be

```
..."signatures":["SIG_K1_SIGNATUREJH1J2j124235HJWEHFE"]...
```

or

```
..."signatures":["SIG_R1_SIGNATUREJH1J2j124235HJWEHFE"]...
```

Comment: `Unable to decode base58 string EOS4wJVpa8YBT1BnBtGHXM8PgQr9cxD2TuZVGhciLZZwp4AsjStoC`
New error is something like this with STG_K1 or STG_R1.

Comment: FYI, I am using cleos wallet keys to see the signature.

Comment: sry, my fault. Obviously you are adding the key as the signature - but you have to add the signature instead.

Comment: You mean the openssl signature for my local machine? Or something else? Where can I find it?

Comment: You need to generate a signature based on base58-transaction-hash and your private-key. OpenSSL doesn't support the ECDSA needed and unfortunately I'm not a php-dev. Have you seen this one? https://packagist.org/packages/manamine/php-eos-rpc-sdk

Comment: what you see with cleos wallet keys is not signatures, it's keys.

Comment: Okay, It seems some useful stuff on that URL, let me check that. Thanks for the help.